# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have issue running below shell script

```
git diff -U0 HEAD^ HEAD pkg.json | grep "^\\+\\s" | grep -o \'"v.*"\' | sed \'s/"//g\' | \
xargs -I{} sh -c \'docker pull alpine:{} \'
```

The error is

```
./shell/shell.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `sed` command:

```
sed \'s/"//g\'
```

When you have `\'` this is an escaped single quote. Then you later have a `"`, and there are no more `"` characters for the rest of the script. So `bash` searches the rest of your script for the closing `"` and fails to find it.

What I believe you meant to do was not escape the single quotes:

```sh
sed 's/"//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `sed` command is messed up. `sed 's/"//g'` will work.

Try this:

```
git diff -U0 HEAD^ HEAD pkg.json | grep "^\\+\\s" | grep -o \'"v.*"\' | sed 's/"//g' | \
xargs -I{} sh -c \'docker pull alpine:{} \'
```