# Extract string from file

Tags: grep

I have a file with below text

```
diff --git a/pkg.json b/pkg.json
index 24e8af4..9d0fbf0 100644
--- a/pkg.json
+++ b/pkg.json
@@ -2,0 +3 @@
+        " v5.1.1 " ,
```

How  can i extract just string v5.1.1

I tried

```
grep "^\\+\\s"  | sed 's/"//g'
```

which gives

```
+ v5.1.1 ,
```

Comment: `grep -o 'v[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' file`, or more explicit `grep -o 'v[0-9][.][0-9][.][0-9]' file`(also you file isn't javascript -- omit the "Run Code" tags `:)`

Comment: You are welcome -- good luck with your scripting..

Comment: Instead of processing with diff then grep, can't you process both input JSON with `jq` and do the version comparison using a `jq` script?
You are obviously trying to parse JSON with shell, then use `jq` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387152/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-fi

Comment: Please post an example/extract of your `pkg.json` so I can help you with using `jq` to compare versions.

Comment: `awk '{print $3}' <(tail -1 inputfile)`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, try following `grep` code. Simple explanation would be, running OP's `diff` command and passing its output as an standard input to `grep` command. In `grep` using `oP` options to get only matched content(by regex) then using regex to match version number (match v followed by digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by `.`, having 0 or more occurrences of this, followed by digits(1 or more occurrences) here).

```
diff --git a/pkg.json b/pkg.json | grep -oP 'v(\d+.)*\d+'
```

Comment: Fancy, using the POSIX regexs `:)`

Answer (score 2):

An approach using Basic Regular expressions can be:

```
grep -o 'v[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' file
```

(where the `'.'` will match any character)

However, to be more explicit on the separation of 3 numeric digits by `'.'` (literal period) you can use:

```
grep -o 'v[0-9][.][0-9][.][0-9]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <file> | grep -o 'v[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]'
```

Comment: `cat file | ...` is a *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Unless you are concatenating two files, `command file` or `command < file` are the better choices.

Comment: This doesn't look to be working, since you are not passing any file to `cat` command IMHO. btw you don't need to use `cat` with `grep` command.